# In PHP dependency injection how to instantiate a class according to the parameters defined in constructor

Tags: java, php, dependency-injection

When programming with Magento (PHP), I practiced DI when overriding classes. I can freely add any parameters in any order as I wish in the constructor functions to inject service dependencies, something as below:

```
class X
{
    protected $service_a = null;
    protected $service_b = null;
    ...
    public function __construct(ServiceA $a, ServiceB $b, ... )
    {
        $this->service_a  = $a;
        $this->service_b  = $b;
        ...
    }
}
```

Somehow, in somewhere, when class X is instantiated, the system could automatically detect the parameter definition in the constructor of class X. Does not matter how do I modify the definition, the system always pass the correct services to the constructor. In Angular, the same story.

My question is how to make it possible in PHP and javascript??? If I define my own class, I have to instantiate it according to the constructor definition. How do they make the process (detect the parameter in constructor) done automatically?

Comment: Is this question about PHP, Java or JavaScript? I also can't figure out what you mean about Magento creating class instances automagically. Sure, it's crystal clear that arguments should be instances of `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` but can PHP know if you want to use an existing variable or create a new instance and, in such case, how to create it?

Comment: In magento (PHP), Angular (Typescript), they use the same principle, inject dependency through constructor. And it does not matter if I do __construct(ServiceA $a, ServiceB $b, ... ) or __construct(ServiceB $b, ServiceA $a, ... ). The frameworks can always detect the parameter structure and pass the correct service to it. I want know how it is possible for the framework to detect the parameter structure in the constructor?

Comment: They surely impose some rules, like registering services in some place or using some convention. I doubt you can e.g. define `DateTime` as param type and get it populated automatically.

Comment: Yes, services need to be registered in some place. I heard about "reflection" in Javascript and PHP, maybe the frameworks use "reflection" to analysis constructor definition first and instantiate class according to the reflection results. It sounds doable, yet I am still wondering what is behind the scenes.

Comment: You'll need a container (something that's responsible about providing dependencies and resolving them for classes) if you ask about a known thing the container will resolve it automatically, if it's unknown you have to define it in your container and it will be passed automatically like other known things

Comment: I still don't understand the exact question (or even what language it's about) but Magento's Dependency Injection is documented [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html). It doesn't seem particularly easy. Perhaps you want to learn from something simpler like [Pimple](https://pimple.symfony.com/).

Comment: I did some investigation these days about the question. I found that it does not matter about the language (PHP or Typescript). Also It does not matter about the framework (zend, laravel, angular). When injecting service from constructor, no matter if you do "construct(ServiceA $a, ServiceB $b, ... )" or "construct(ServiceB $b, ServiceA $a, ... )" The frameworks always inject the correct service to the constructor. I am now pretty sure (in PHP) they use "reflection" to achieve that. The DI containers use "reflection" to analyze the constructor definition and instantiate a class accordingly.

Comment: Normally we defined class constructor first and then instantiate with "new" operator anywhere we need. If we changed the parameter structure of constructor, all instantiation need to be re-coded according to the change. However in DI, we can modify parameter structure of constructor without caring about the instantiation codes (they remain unchanged for sure). I did not understand how could that happen. Now I know they leverage "reflection" to get it done. Check this [article](https://indigotree.co.uk/automatic-dependency-injection-with-phps-reflection-api/)

Comment: Reflection makes it possible to determine that a function constructor expects an argument that's an instance of a given class. That can help when there's strict context (e.g. you're passing around instances of already initialised objects like `Request` or `Controller`). I mean, it's just one more tool. You can also do as Pimple and define dependencies as [Callbacks / Callables](http://php.net/callable),